# Using Sencha Cmd, how can I NOT build MyApp-all.css?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

We are using Sencha Cmd to build our ExtJS 4.2.1 app.

Using Sencha Cmd, how can I NOT build MyApp-all.css?

We are using a custom theme so we don't need the css file Sencha Cmd usually builds.

The app works great, but we need to stop the building of MyApp-all.css.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And I don't want the <link> line in index.html that refers to the css file.

Comment: Anyone have insights?

Answer (score 0):

I can do the following to delete the entire resources directory and remove the link tag, but that's overkill as far as I am concerned.

```
<target name="-after-page">
    <fileset id="html.fileset"
        dir="${build.dir}"
        includes="${app.page.name}"/>

    <replaceregexp replace="" flags="g"
        match='\&lt;\s*link\s*rel="stylesheet"\s*href=".*-all.css"\/\&gt;'>
        <fileset refid="html.fileset"/>
    </replaceregexp>
</target>

<target name="-after-build">
    <delete dir="${build.resources.dir}"/>
</target>
```